# If a spell has verbal and/or somatic components, are they necessary for its casting?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

If a spell has verbal and/or somatic components, are they absolutely vital for its casting?

Let me give a clear example: suppose a wizard is trying to cast Detect Magic on a creature they are speaking to, but they don't want the creature to notice the spell is being cast. Detect Magic has both verbal and somatic components, so the wizard might comply with the somatic portion by just forcefully gesticulating as one would in an energetic conversation. But they might not be able to actually speak out the proper incantations.

Another situation: a sorcerer has both her hands tied behind her back and is trying to cast Acid Splash. She can't perform the somatic portion of the spell, but she can easily speak out the incantations.

In these situations, can the spells simply not be cast? Or can the spells still be cast, but with some kind of penalties added? And if the answer is the latter, which penalties should I consider?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks for editing the title, @V2Blast! Much clearer.

Comment: Is the question getting downvoted because it's too obvious or something? Sorry, I'm just asking so I can avoid getting downvoted with future questions I may have. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I suspect it's because you're asking a question that's easily answered by the rules.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## You must be able to provide all components.

This is the rule from the *Spellcasting > Casting a Spell > Components* section of the [*Basic Rules*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components) or *Player's Handbook*, emphasis mine:

> A spell's components are the physical requirements you must meet in order to cast it. Each spell's description indicates whether it requires verbal (V), somatic (S), or material (M) components. **If you can't provide one or more of a spell's components, you are unable to cast the spell.**

You explicitly must be able to provide *all* components to be able to cast a spell. (The exception would be if you have a feature that allows you to ignore a component. In your example, the tied-up sorcerer might be able to use [Subtle Spell metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) to ignore the components they can't provide due to the bindings, but that's not the general rule.)

Answer (score 7):

### The VSM components are vital to casting a spell

> If a spell requires a somatic component, **the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.**

### A character who is unable to meet the V or S or M component of a spell, can't cast that spell.

Answer (score -1):

## Yes, they're required, but they're also much easier to perform than you'd think.

Well, lets get this straight.

**Verbal** components must be spoken to use the spell, even if they are whispered or muttered (perhaps when your wizard in the first scenario lets a different character speak). If it's an offensive spell that really doesn't require secrecy, then just say it.

**Somatic** components are the real issue. If your sorcerer cannot move her hands at all, then she may not cast the spell. Unless the gestures are specified, if she can move her hands in the direction of the target, they can cast the spell. This may also depend on the generosity of your DM, as the rules aren't really specified. Look at page 27 on rituals in the DMG and at the more specific rituals in the Player's Handbook.

**Material** components *must* be used, if needed. There shouldn't be any dispute over that.

I hope that helped! :)

Comment: Your Verbal paragraph seems incomplete. Did you forget to finish it or accidentally delete part of it? Also, [relevant Sage Advice tweet](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/11/17/audible-verbal-component/) about how audible verbal components have to be.

Comment: I apologize profusely. I forgot to finish it in my hurry to grab my books. Sorry, I hope this did not affect your opinion of my answer.

Comment: Material components are not always required. For material requirements without a cost an arcane/divine/druidic focus can be used instead

Comment: If you take a close look, my post says *if needed*. I also put on the part about the DM's generosity.

Comment: "Rituals" have a special meaning in 5e. I assume you mean spells in general. That said, I'm not sure what you're referring to when you mention page 27 of the DMG; there's no mentions of spells there, as that section's about creating a campaign. As for what linksassin said, if you're implying that the phrase "if needed" covers cases where they can be substituted by a component pouch/spellcasting focus, that's not really clear in the answer... but OP didn't ask about material components in the question so I guess that's not that important here.

Comment: Also, the rules about somatic components aren't that vague; [the rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#SomaticS) say: "If a spell requires a somatic component, the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures." ..I suppose what constitutes a "free hand" might be seen as ambiguous when it comes to restraints.

Comment: In my book, that is vague... if the hand is free, but the arm is not, some would consider it  enough. Would you please stop slamming me now? I am in the Central time zone and would eventually like to get to bed. Thanks so much,

Comment: Suggesting improvements to your answer isn't "slamming" you. But sleep is more important than rules debates. Good night :)